# How does some apps to get the hostname of device based on ip?

Tags: node.js, networking, dns

Have you seen those apps which explore your local network looking for devices?
Well, I would like to know how they get (mostly) the names of devices!

Does anyone know? Because I am building an application which needs to get (if possible) the hostname of the local devices..

Comment: I have started thinking they could be using the netbios name which is set in most devices

Comment: Did you ever found a solution for nodejs? How would you get the netbios name in nodejs?

Comment: @Laurens, wow, such an old post. I finally did it with SNMP, for my purpose it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

Local network device discovery is often done by a zeroconf implementation (e.g. Apple services typically use Bonjour services to discover local device names).

If you wanted to explore this type of service for use in nodeJS, then maybe have a look at https://github.com/agnat/node_mdns. I've never used it myself but it does seem reasonably popular and stable.

Otherwise just do some research generally around zeroconf/mdns and make a decision based on your needs.

Comment: You are correct, and I was too. Take a look at this: https://github.com/angryziber/ipscan/blob/master/src/net/azib/ipscan/fetchers/HostnameFetcher.java

I started searching into the Angry IP Scanner source code, and I found that it do it by different methods, gethostbyaddr, mdns, netbios, it tries them, and get the possible hostname!...

So I am going to implement them in my node app, I hadn't payed attention to mdns for zero conf devices... Thanks at all! ;)

Comment: Maybe I am needing some extra help, because I am not making it work! As far as I could see, node-mdns let me see the "published" services for zero conf, but I have not seen any option to get a special value such as the hostname. Sorry, any help?

Comment: Services like mdns and zeroconf etc require that the other devices on your network are "broadcasting" their device names through this service. If you're just trying to get the hostnames of the devices on the local network, and these devices aren't going to be broadcasting through an mdns service, then you'll have to try NetBIOS queries or inspecting your arp table (arp -a). DNS would be a better setup if all the devices on the network are managed by you.

Comment: I can see the name in the of devices in the "browse" result! But I am not being able to point my request to an specific device. What I mean is that the node-mdns only allow me to do a global browse, it shows all the devices publishing services and its data, in which it is included the hostname! But I would like to get it just for an specific IP address. Sorry for my English, I talk Spanish, I hope you understand me

Comment: So am I correct in assuming that you wish to give an IP address and get a hostname? See if this answers your question: http://serverfault.com/questions/143184/how-do-i-get-the-machine-name-from-an-ip-via-multicast-dns

Comment: I had already read that post before, but I don't want to depend on system commands if possible

Comment: I have been reading the code of Angry IP Scanner, but I have not been able to translate the code of the mdns hostname getter into nodejs code. So I am stuck

Comment: Can you give a more detailed description of the problem you're trying to solve and the purpose of your code? There may a better solution if we can understand your requirements better...

Comment: I have write an application to monitor network, it just ping devices and set an UP or DOWN state, I would like to get the devices hostnames, that's why I am trying, I tried to read the RFC about mdns but I could find the way I can ask  the device for an specific value (such as the hostname). Because I could try to send an UDP packet, and get the response but I don't know what do I have to send in the packet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101209/discussion-between-seonixx-and-cristian-perez).